# Repeater does not show data

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

As posted earlier ,  Here is my HTML :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/VendorMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PastOrders.aspx.cs" Inherits="PastOrders" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

    <br />
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 mb">
                <a href="VendorProfile.aspx">
                    <div class="twitter-panel pn">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x"></i>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </div>
        </a>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

</asp:Content>
```

C# :

```
public partial class PastOrders : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["vendor"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ArrayList values = new ArrayList();

                values.Add(new Testing
                {
                    Name = "Caterer"
                });

                values.Add(new Testing
                {
                    Name = "Florist"
                });

                values.Add(new Testing
                {
                    Name = "Cab Services"
                });

                rptr.DataSource = values;
                rptr.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("VendorLogin.aspx");
        }
    }



    public class Testing
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Now i want to generate 3 separate divs, with the Names on them as : "Caterer","Florist","Cab Services",etc.

Instead it is only generating one div with all the 3 names inside it .

I tried formatting it with the **Header Template** and the **Footer Template** where i put the parent divs and the anchor tag in the **Header Template** and the closing of the same in the **Footer Template** . Bt it doesn't produce the expected result still.

Comment: What dataSource did you bind to your repeater? with data there will be no repeating element! see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx) Furthermore naming your class the same like a .NetFX class is not the best idea!

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz : Please check the updated C# code . Still it is not showing the "Name" i am setting into the objects , Instead it is only creating the corresponding  number of div elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you do bind data, but **you do not access your data** within your repater. Change it to

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="divStyle" id="divStyle">
                 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

and it should work!

Comment: :Yea it did work ! and if i want to apply css to the same generated divs where in styling is **Nested** . How should i go about that ? Should I keep only one DataBinder.Eval() ? where the text of my intended content will appear ? Or should i use it at every step of of the nesting of the div element?

Comment: I don't quite get you... could you update your question and describe what you exactly want (eg. show possible html result)

Comment: Please see my updated question .. I want **3 separate divs** instead  i am only getting one with all the three names inside it. Appreciate your help in this one too!

Comment: You put your div markup in header and footer template. So it will only be rendered once. Put them in ItemTemplate and they will be repeated too. See my original answer - which will render one div per item in dataSource!

Comment: Okay this did work ! Thanks ,  Bt this is spoiling my **CSS** and the div are generated one below the other with not even the same size. How should i mend that one ? Like putting a float : left or something like that ?

Comment: I think this should be a separate question.. Put your html and css code in it, and describe exactly how it should look, what you have tried aso.

Comment: Sure thing! I ll do that now!

Comment: Please if you could help me , i have posted my new question . Thank you !